# npm modules package.json corrupted

Tags: node.js, npm

My modules' package.json files seem to be spontaneously corrupting, filling up with garbage characters. The opening characters are always, "♥?????PB?8?N???↨☻??lp`↨T▼?◄♂?U" . I have no idea what triggers the corruption. The modules install initially without a problem, but a few hours or a day later they are all messed up. Any ideas what could be causing this?

I've attached a [screenshot of the problem here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzWtC.png) and here's a sample of the console output:

```
npm WARN Failed to parse json
npm WARN Unexpected token '\u0003' at 1:1
npm WARN ♥?????PB?8?N???↨☻??lp`↨T▼?◄♂?U?Fm?
npm WARN ^
npm WARN File: C:\Temp\nodejs\voting-server\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\glob
\package.json
npm WARN Failed to parse json
npm WARN Unexpected token '\u0003' at 1:1
npm WARN ♥?????PB?8?N???↨☻??lp`↨T▼?◄♂?U↨???+?w>]EsK??&?u?_?☺?►?s???F?^??g?¶?x???
Ie????◄
npm WARN ^
npm WARN File: C:\Temp\nodejs\voting-server\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\ms\p
ackage.json
npm WARN Failed to parse json
npm WARN Unexpected token '\u0003' at 1:1
npm WARN ♥?????PB?8?N???↨☻??lp`↨T▼?◄♂?U8???♥c→?z♫;X?^??♣?jqU{?ƒ◄:bD?K,?;U↕?↔T`}z
yw??u?
npm WARN ^
npm WARN File: C:\Temp\nodejs\voting-server\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\supp
orts-color\package.json
```

Comment: there may be a virus in your system ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have:

- some character encoding messed up
- disk failure (check health of your disk)
- malware problem (make sure to scan your system)